# Convert the string address into an actual binary format

Tags: python, hex

I am trying to accept the address in the big-endian from user `00401521` and then converting it to hex in little-endian form

The code I am trying is

```
if len(addr) != 8:
    raise ValueError("Required the address as 00000000")
a, b, c, d = addr[:2], addr[2:4], addr[4:6], addr[6:]
addr = "\\x%s\\x%s\\x%s\\x%s" % (d, c, b, a)
print(addr)
```

This works fine but when I change

```
- addr = "\\x%s\\x%s\\x%s\\x%s" % (d, c, b, a)
+ addr = "\x%s\x%s\x%s\x%s" % (d, c, b, a)
```

It is failing with the following message

[image]

The value I want to store in addr variable is exactly `\x21\x15\x40\x00`

Comment: Note, your first approach *doesn't work*.

Comment: Yes it didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the value "00401521" is neither big-endian or little-endian.  When you're looking at an integer value, endianness does not apply.  It doesn't become endian until you store it as bytes.

Your desire to have "\x21\x15\x40\x00" is odd.  "\x21" is the exclamation mark, and "\x40" is the @ sign, and would usually be typed like that.  How, exactly, will use this value?  Because I suspect this is not really the representation you want.  This code IS converting the value into a 4-byte string, and it can be sent as a 4-byte buffer to a device, but when it prints, Python will show the non-printable characters with the \x notation.

```
import struct

addr = '00401521'

b = struct.pack('I', int(addr,16))
print(b)
```

Output:

```
b'!\x15@\x00'
```